# BSOD in windows7 because of Simple tcl script

Tags: windows-xp, tcl, windows-7-x64, expect

I am using Windows7 64-bit and TCL8.4. i have a simple script as follows:

```
package require Expect;
spawn ping 192.168.25.23 -n 15;
#NOTE: output of the ping is "request timed out" for my testing purpose.;
set id $spawn_id;
expect -i $id "Ping statistics *";
```

This script is giving Blue Screen Error of Death.

Same script i ran in another machine having windowsXP. here i did not observed any such issue.

FYI:

default timeout in "ping" is 4sec and that of "Expect" is 10sec.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: I expected to post "worked for me"... Nope, it BSOD'd me as well.  Tcl 8.5, Win 7 64-bit.  I have a guess that the way Expect is closing the spawn is not playing nicely with ping, since the BSOD was citing something about locked pages, but I was too surprised to take good notes. >_<

Comment: AIUI, Expect for Windows uses some funky debugging mode stuff to do its magic. This report would appear to indicate that this sort of thing is subtly broken on Win 7. (Can anyone reproduce on Win8?)

Comment: Ok, BSOD by a user space program. Nice. That's like making Tcl coredump from a safe interp. (Both shouldn't be possible).

Comment: I hope other aspects of expect work?  Use plain ole' tcl and exec or open for a task like that. expect scripts were, are and always will be hard to get working, and fragile as eggs.